# Radicchio/Chicory from Seed

Tags: indoors, seeds, planting, germination, leaf-vegetables

I am growing radicchio from seed for the first time and am worried about its germination.

Should I start the seeds in soil or soak them first? Also, would it be recommended to place the pot under grow lamps indoors during the germination period or only after they have sprouted?

Finally, if I would like 18 plants to grow successfully, how many seeds should I plant? (ie what is the ratio of seed to successful plant)

*Everything will be grown indoors with access to grow lamps at a temperature around 18-22 degrees Celsius

*Any watering/general tips welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well soaking seed can help the germination rate of just about anything when the seeds won't get lost or gummed up in the water, but it's also usually not necessary unless you have old seeds and you need maximum output. You can also soak seeds between the folds of a wet paper towel and you can measure your germination rate by planting 10 seeds in the paper towels and count how many sprout.

Personally, I would just sow 2 or 3 seeds in each *space* whatever that space may be whether in rows in a box or in peat pots or regular 12 inch terra cotta pots.

When the seedlings have grown enough to know which are the strongest of each *space*, cull out the ones you aren't going to keep.

Most store bought seeds have a good germination rate, so you don't usually need to over do it unless your seeds are old.